# wordpress display featured image

Tags: wordpress

I am currently trying to display my post's featured image in a horizontal slider that shows three images at the time, and then the next three once clicked (right / left), however I can not get the featured images to show up.

My code:

```
    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('collections'); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">Collections</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <div class="images" >
                        <a href="#" class="arrow prev" ></a>
                        <a href="#" class="arrow next"></a>
                        <div class="wrap"  >
                            <?php 
                            $url = get_permalink();
                            $images = the_post_thumbnail();
                            $count = is_array($images) ? count($images) : 0;
                            if($count)
                            {   
                                $n = 0;                         //$images[$i]['url']
                                for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
                                {
                                    $l = $i * 100;
                                    $t = $i * -300;
                                    $big = image_downsize($images[$i]['id'], 'full');
                                    $medium = image_downsize($images[$i]['id'], 'medium');
                                    echo '<a href="', $url,'" 
                                    class=" '.(($n==0)?'n':'').' image-holder"  '.(($n==0)?'id="n'.$i.'"':'').'><img src="',$big[0],'"
                                     class="image"   /></a>';
                                    if($n < 2)
                                    $n++ ;
                                    else
                                    $n = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div style="clear:both"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: Check your echo statement. It looks like you are trying to use commas for concatenation.

Comment: You should use `get_the_post_thumbnail` to get the featured image: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail Note that this function will never return an array, instead use `has_post_thumbnail` to check: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Featured image is only one per post/page and you can get it using

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

This function directly prints the image (an img tag) and `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function returns an image so you have to echo it. Your code and question is confusing because you can't have three featured images for a single post/page but can have multiple images attached to a post/page. if you are trying to get all images then you can check following articles.

1. [Display All Images Attached to a Post in WordPress](http://www.tommaitland.net/2012/10/display-all-images-attached-to-a-post-in-WordPress/).
2. [display all images attached to a post without a plugin](http://return-true.com/2010/02/display-all-images-attached-to-a-post-without-a-plugin/).

Comment: @The Alpha, may I ask you to have a look at a wordpress custom field related question here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782429/wordpress-make-custom-field-values-clickable-to-retrive-them-later ?